# Python sort CSV File

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

Hey I have a CSV file with many rows but one of the row constantly repeats. Is it possible to only keep the first name for that row and keep all other data. I tried with pandas but pandas asks for a function such as aggregate sum. My data in the CSV file is like.

```
H1 h2 h3 h4
A 1 2 3 4
A 2 3 4 5
A 3 4 5 6
B 1 2 3 4
B 2 3 4 5
B 3 4 5 6
C 1 2 3 4
C 2 3 4 5
C 3 4 5 6
```

Each one of these has a header. Which are shown by h1-h4.
My data is not like this, it contains real text values.

I want to rearrange the data so it looks like this.

```
A 
   1 2 3 4
   2 3 4 5
   3 4 5 6
B
   1 2 3 4
   2 3 4 5
   3 4 5 6

C
   1 2 3 4
   2 3 4 5
   3 4 5 6
```

Or

```
 A 1 2 3 4
   2 3 4 5
   3 4 5 6

B  1 2 3 4
   2 3 4 5
   3 4 5 6

C  1 2 3 4
   2 3 4 5
   3 4 5 6
```

So basically I want it to group by the first header name which is h1. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Ok... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some of the actual rows from your CSV file, it is not clear how they all look.

Comment: hey is it a bit clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work, it assumes your source data is space delimited (as you have shown), if it uses commas or tabs, you will need to change the delimiter I have used.

```
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r") as f_input, open("output.csv", "wb") as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=" ")
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    headers = next(csv_input)

    cur_row = ""
    for cols in csv_input:
        if cur_row != cols[0]:
            cur_row = cols[0]
            csv_output.writerow([cur_row])
        csv_output.writerow(cols[1:])
```

Giving you an output CSV file as follows:

```
A
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
B
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
C
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
```

Tested using Python 2.7

To add the headers for each group, change the first `writerow` line as follows:

```
csv_output.writerows([[cur_row], headers])
```

Giving the following output:

```
A
H1,h2,h3,h4
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
B
H1,h2,h3,h4
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
C
H1,h2,h3,h4
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
```

Comment: hey is it possible to leave an empty space so it has a space before the numbers so there is no writing under the letters in the csv file? because the headers will not match the data.

Comment: Do you mean, add a blank line after 'A'?

Comment: or is it possible to write the headers right underneath the letters?

Comment: for example a line that takes h2 h3 h4 shown in the original question and writes it write underneath the A,B,C,D. h2 represents column1, h3 represents column2

Comment: last part that i need help with is. H1 is the header for the letters for example A,B,C,D. is it possible to skip H1 from the headers?

Comment: You can simply change `headers` to `headers[1:]` to skip the first one.